# Calling same page with Ajax in separate DIV's

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

If I make an ajax call using jQuery and do this inside tabs for example, I then want to call the same page inside a different tab which is just a div really.

Each page will then bring the same tag ID's onto the page.

Is the only solution to this to use an iframe rather than an ajax call?

I basically want each tab to have the same tags and ID's in it.

Thanks

Comment: ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: You can't have the same id twice... better to use id's for your tabs, then classes inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not valid to do so, you may still be able to get away with it... I imagine you'd just need to specify which object you mean when referring to an ID...

`$('#div1 #itemId')` and `$('#div2 #itemId')`

I've never tried this, since its BAD CODING to do so.

A better bet is to give the elements CLASS names, as opposed to IDs - and you'll be able to accomplish this in a VALID way.

`$('#div1 .itemId')` and `$('#div2 .itemId')`

Comment: I didn't propose it as a solution. I answered the question that was asked and offered an alternative (which may have been in the making when you commented).

Comment: ok thank you! I think that answers my question :) I will probably use iframes. Its no problem, just a bit messier as I need to re-include all scripts etc in the child page and its hard to reference bits in the parent. Thanks

Comment: UGH - That is a **Bad** idea. Just use the class names instead of IDs.

Comment: indeed. He answered my question whether it was bad coding or not, but a viable option if I wanted ;)

Comment: wow this worked. I made it dynamic by using a variable of the tabIndex inside the selector :) Surely its not 'BAD' coding if its done using a variable of the selectedIndex for the current tab?

Comment: As long as any two elements on one web page have the same ID, it is poor coding. That is the entire purpose of classes. If you changed your ids to `theItemId1` and `theItemId2` (to indicate tab 1 and tab 2) that's OK then. If my code worked for you, kindly select it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: great thanks. I may try using the same logic in each ID, so it sets the tabIndex after every ID. Would solve the issue!